# UINavigationBar with image and default gradient background with iOS5

Tags: image, background, ios5, uinavigationbar, gradient

I'm attempting to use the new `[UINavigationBar appearance]` functionality in iOS5 to add a logo image to the UINavigationBars in my application.    Primarily, I'd like to keep the default gradient, but center a transparent png in the NavBar.  The logo image is roughly 120 pixels wide (240 pixels@2x).

I have first attempted this by setting the background image. The default behavior for `setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:` appears to be to tile the image, and all transparent parts show the default navbar background color, black.  I can also set the background color via the appearance modifier, and get a flat color background, but I'd really like to get the original gradient behavior without maintaining a separate image resource for it.  It also makes it easier to adjust in code, since I can adjust the tint there, rather than re-generating a new image if I decide to change it.

What I'm trying to use:

```
UIImage *logoImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"logoImage"];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:logoImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this two ways. If you want to always have the image in the navigation bar, then create an image view and set it as a subview of the navigation bar:

```
[self setLogoImageView:[[UIImageView alloc] init]];
[logoImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"]];
[logoImageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];

CGRect navFrame = [[navController navigationBar] frame];

float imageViewHeight = navFrame.size.height - 9;

float x_pos = navFrame.origin.x + navFrame.size.width/2 - 111/2;

float y_pos = navFrame.size.height/2 - imageViewHeight/2.0;

CGRect logoFrame = CGRectMake(x_pos, y_pos, 111, imageViewHeight);

[logoImageView setFrame:logoFrame];
[[[self navigationController] navigationBar] addSubview:logoImageView];
```

If you only want to display the logo in a certain view, then set the view's navigation item:

```
[logoImageView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
[[self navigationItem] setTitleView:logoImageView];
```